# For loop for text manipulation not working - CMD

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a file abc1.txt with the following contents:

```
a1
b2
c3
```

My .CMD file contains:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in (abc1.txt) do (
   set gurl=%%g
   set gfname=%gurl:~-1%
   echo %gfname%
   echo %gurl%
   echo %%g 
)
echo on
```

My output on running the CMD file is:

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
a1
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
b2
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
c3
```

I'm just not able to understand why the variables gurl and gfname aren't getting printed!
Please help. :(

Answer (score 0):

#### I'm don't understand why the variables `gurl` and `gfname` aren't getting printed

You have `enabledelayedexpansion` but you are not **using** delayed expansion.

To use delayed expansion you need to replace `%variable%` with `!variable!` as follows.

Corrected batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@ECHO off
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in (abc1.txt) do (
   set gurl=%%g
   set gfname=!gurl:~-1!
   echo !gfname!
   echo !gurl!
   echo %%g 
)
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
> test
1
a1
a1
2
b2
b2
3
c3
c3
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.